# Map parent value to a property in nested dictionary with JSONModel

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, jsonmodel

I'm not even sure if this is possible but I'd like to map a property on a node to each item in an array which is also a property on the node.

JSON example

```
"productType" : {
  "name" : "foo",
  "products" : []
}
```

So I want the value of name to be a property on each product.

I have a productType model set up which has an NSArray on there and everything is mapped by JSONModel. I was thinking there could be a way using the keypath in JSONKeyMapper? But couldn't find anything.

Comment: *So I want the value of name to be a property on each product.*  If I'm understanding what you're saying (it's far from clear), you want a dictionary.

Comment: And for something that simple you'd be much better off tossing out JSONModel and just using NSJSONSerialization and then doing whatever object mapping you need in code.

Comment: I've got a ProductType model and a Product model. ProductType has an array of Products. These are built up through JSONModel and initWithDictionary. But I want to be able to get ProductType.name from a Product object. I was wondering if there's a way to map that in the keyMapper method that JSONModel uses.

Comment: It's a little more complicated than this in reality I was just abstracting the relevant information.

Comment: change your model and add name there

Comment: You're unclear.  Do you want to say `something.foo` and get the "products" array?  Or simply say `something.name` and get "foo"?

Comment: it would be more like product.productTypeName or even product.productType.name and get "foo"

Comment: Nevermind I decided to take the hit from looping through the product types retroactively and getting the name that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this with `JSONModel`.

Assume we have the following model:

```
@class MyModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *products;

@end
```

---

If the complete JSON doc looks like this:

```
{
  "productType1": {
    "name": "foo",
    "products": []
  },
  "productType2": {
    "name": "foo",
    "products": []
  },
  "productType3": {
    "name": "foo",
    "products": []
  }
}
```

then you should use one of the [`[MyModel dictionaryOfModelsFrom...];`](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/blob/master/JSONModel/JSONModel/JSONModel.h#L234-L236) methods.

---

If it looks like this:

```
{
  "productTypes": {
    "productType1": {
      "name": "foo",
      "products": []
    },
    "productType2": {
      "name": "foo",
      "products": []
    },
    "productType3": {
      "name": "foo",
      "products": []
    }
  }
}
```

Then you should use another model like this:

```
@class MyModelContainer

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary <MyModel> *productTypes;

@end
```